# How can I enable the option `-short-paths` in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

When I try to build some projects, such as **Jane Street's** `Hello World Core`

https://bitbucket.org/yminsky/core-hello-world,

it gives me such an error:

> ocamlfind ocamlc -c -w @A-4-33-23 **-short-paths** -g -annot -thread
>   -package core,sexplib.syntax,bin_prot.syntax,comparelib.syntax,fieldslib.syntax,variantslib.syntax,async,core_extended
>   -syntax camlp4o -o hello_world.cmi hello_world.mli
>
> **ocamlc: unknown option `-short-paths'**. usage: ocamlfind ocamlc [options] file ...

**What is `-short-paths` and how can I enable this option?**

Comment: @rajendra_prasad, why edited my question like that. it is very ugly now. i am changing it back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an option that was added by Jacques Garrigue in the development version of OCaml, but is not yet in any released version. You could use the development version of the language to try that (probably not worth the effort and possible inconveniences), or wait a few months for the new version that will have this option.

Comment: oh, really? it is just wield that it is not mentioned like this in any where. https://bitbucket.org/yminsky/core-hello-world/src/85769e337d3e70a4b9e3246503f59991c109afe8/PREREQUISITES.md?at=default

Comment: The page instructs you to install 4.01.0dev+trunk.